# calculate total Miles in a polygon using Google Map

Tags: google-maps, distance, layers

I have an application that allows the users to create any custom polygon layer on top of google maps, i am interested to know if their is a way to select the road layer in this polygon and then calculate the total miles for these roads.

Comment: I'd say it is *possible*, but probably it could be hard, complicated and a bit slow...

Comment: This uses a users mouse click creates a point and polygon based on radius creates distances traveled in all directions from that point quickly - http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html